# How to create a new dataframe from a dictionary and a list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So, I have a dictionary like:

```
d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'colnames':['a','b','d','e']}
list_of_ids = [1,2]
```

I am trying to create a DataFrame like:

```
id, col1, colnames
1,  1,     a
1, 2,    b
1,3, c

...
2,1,a
2,1,b

.. and so on
```

So, basically, for each element in list, generate all the possible column entries.

How can I do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) directly.

```
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(list_of_ids, d['col1'], d['colnames'])), 
                  columns=['id', 'col1', 'colnames'])

#     id col1  colnames
# 0    1    1         a
# 1    1    1         b
# 2    1    1         d
# 3    1    1         e
# 4    1    2         a
# ...
```

With your current input size, this approach seems reasonable enough. However, if you intend to perform this operation on a much much larger dataset, you'll want to use a NumPy solution like [piRSquared's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42912804/4686625).

Comment: Great answer + 1

Comment: Ah product can take more than one parameter. V nice

Answer (score 2):

***using `numpy.repeat`***

```
# the data
d = {'col1': np.arange(1, 6), 'colnames':list('abde'), 'id': [1, 2]}

# calculate length of each sub-list
lengths = {k: len(v) for k, v in d.items()}

# calculate product of all lengths...
# ... then the product of all but current.
# this provides the value we must repeat by.
p = np.product(list(lengths.values()))
p_ = {k: p // v for k, v in lengths.items()}

# perform the repeat within a dictionary comprehension
# and pass to the dataframe constructor
pd.DataFrame({k: np.repeat(v, p_[k]) for k, v in d.items()})
```

---

```
    col1 colnames  id
0      1        a   1
1      1        a   1
2      1        a   1
3      1        a   1
4      1        a   1
5      1        a   1
6      1        a   1
7      1        a   1
8      2        a   1
9      2        a   1
10     2        b   1
11     2        b   1
...
```

---

***timing with given data***

[image]

***with much bigger data***

[image]

Comment: @Mitch `True` I'll fix in a bit.  Working on better answer

Comment: @Mitch there it is

Comment: Can't benchmark now but that looks very nice, thanks for pinging me! +1

Comment: @Mitch I've added some

Comment: As I'd expect, yeah. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shorter ways to do this but

```
import pandas as pd

out = []
for x in range(1,3):
    for y in range(1,6):
        for z in 'abde':
            out.append([x, y, z]) 
df = pd.DateFrame(out)
```

Substitute your lists/dictionary calls in the appropriate places and you should be good